related to huggingface inference api not working
I have done a simple project which is Text Summarization and I used T5 Model and I successfully fine tuned my model and also inference it on notebook.i have installed bitsandbytes, accelerate,trl and all.
But when push it on hugginface and inference it on server less API. I get error "No package metadata was found for bitsandbytes".
Please suggest me how I can resolve this issue.
I tried all possible solutions
